# fragment lifecycle when pid killed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

This is my second approach to solve this issue, no luck so far.

I've got `MainActivity` which is a launcher activity.

within its `onCreate` method I check if `static endpoints` is initialized.

If no -> start a service and register a receiver (show loader) -> `onReceive` show some fragments

If yes -> show some fragments

This part works great.

**So what is a problem?**

I have `MainActivity` with some fragments. Then I put process into background and do

```
adb shell am kill com.myapp
```

PID is killed. So now I want to launch the app again. Android tries to recreate app state meaning firing :

(For sake of simplicity lets assume that `MainActivity` had only one fragment visible while running)

```
MainActivity : onAttachFragment()
Fragment     : onAttach()
Fragment     : onCreate()
MainActivity : onCreate()
Fragment     : onCreateView()
...
```

The problem is this : When `MainActiviy.onCreate` sees that statics are not initialized then it invokes a call to `Service` and waits for response. **This is a normal start scenario**. But this time `Fragment` is being recreated as well and its lifecycle is mixed with `MainActivity` lifecycle. Becasuse all is happening async I cannot prevent `Fragment`'s `onCreate()`, `onResume()`,`onStart()`, `onCreateView()` from firing.. and some of these methods require statics to be initialized (`MainActivity` did not finish yet the init process) which causes crashes

**So my question is** : how I can prevent `Fragment` from being recreated in this scenario? so that this is preferably a clean `MainActivity` start. Any hints at this point will be appreciated.

Not feasible Solutions or "I Tried it" Solutions :

- save static endpoints on the phone -> cannot happen because endpoints change dynamically every 5 mins
- `singleTop`, `singleTask` for `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this by doing something like this within `MainActivity.onCreate()`:

```
if(!MyStatics.isInitialized())
    super.onCreate(null);
else
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

This causes restart of `Activity` without recreating fragments

Comment: This could be a bad user experience if the fragment has some UI!

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity onCreate method, check if `savedInstanceState is null or not`.

If `that is not null the don't start the service` and create fragments. Note: You should also not call `setContentView` since that will discard the saved instances for the views and even fragment.

And in each `individual Fragment save the state` of the fragment and `restore it` if saveInstance Bundle in OnCreate, onCreateView and onAttach is `not null`.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, im already doing things from your 1st paragraph. As for Fragments.. its not their state that is the problem.. the problem is that I cannot stop their recreation coz it happens before MainActtivity onCreate

Answer (score 0):

In fragments onCreate, check whether the static variables are initialised. If not, then remove the fragment and start the service call. Once the service call is completed, add the fragment as usual.

Comment: Thanks Eldhose, how I remove fragment from fragments onCreate()?

Comment: Inside fragment, you can get the activity instance as context. Using that context, get fragment transaction and call remove(this);

Comment: transactions are async, methods will still fire.. I tried it with executePendingtransactions but still no luck.